# how to get JNA read back function's string result

Tags: jna

```
public interface Kernel32 extends StdCallLibrary {

    int GetComputerNameW(Memory lpBuffer, IntByReference lpnSize);
}

public class Kernel32Test {

    private static final String THIS_PC_NAME = "tiangao-160";

    private static Kernel32 kernel32;

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUp() {
    System.setProperty("jna.encoding", "GBK");
    kernel32 = (Kernel32) Native.loadLibrary("kernel32", Kernel32.class);
    }

    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDown() {
    System.setProperty("jna.encoding", null);
    }

    @Test
    public void testGetComputerNameW() {
        final Memory lpBuffer = new Memory(1024);
        final IntByReference lpnSize = new IntByReference();

        final int result = kernel32.GetComputerNameW(lpBuffer, lpnSize);

        if (result != 0) {
            throw new IllegalStateException(
            "calling 'GetComputerNameW(lpBuffer, lpnSize)'failed，errorcode：" + result);
        }

        final int bufferSize = lpnSize.getValue();
        System.out.println("value of 'lpnSize'：" + bufferSize);
        Assert.assertEquals(THIS_PC_NAME.getBytes().length + 1, bufferSize);

        final String name = lpBuffer.getString(0);
        System.out.println("value of 'lpBuffer'：" + name);
        Assert.assertEquals(THIS_PC_NAME, name);
   }
}
```

The [offical instructions](https://github.com/twall/jna/blob/master/www/FrequentlyAskedQuestions.md#how-do-i-read-back-a-functions-string-result) says use byte[]、char[]、Memory or NIO Buffer for mapping char pointer in c native function.But I tried all of above, and String、WString、StringArrays、class extends PointType etc, all of them are no use.

Out parameter 'lpnSize' can return the corret buffer size，but 'lpBuffer' return 'x>'(i think it's random memory) or nothing no matter I mapping any java type.If i wrote someting to the 'lpBuffer' memory first, it would read the same things after calling native function.

How can I solve the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Pointer.getString(0, true)` to extract the unicode string returned by [GetComputerNameW](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724295%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

**EDIT**

You'll also need to call `GetComputerNameW` again with the length parameter initialized before the function will fill in the result.  Either pass back the same `IntByReference` to a second call, or initialize the `IntByReference` to the size of your `Memory` buffer to have the buffer written to in the first call.

Comment: The problem is the native function just don't write the lpBuffer memory,no matter calling 'GetComputerNameA' or 'GetComputerNameW'.